# Reset BIOS password for HP Probook 440 G6

Tags: bios, password-recovery, reset

I forgot my BIOS password and warrant is also expired. I tried to contact HP support for the SMC file to reset the password which they refused as the policies are changed.

Is there any way to completely reset my laptop.

Comment: ***Did you try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk034zHDwQ_Z4FzAqJxgYLXjJbn3JkA%3A1593012130762&ei=om_zXs-CLtfQ-gSMuYXwBA&q=hp+probook+440+g6+bios+password+reset&oq=hp+probook+440+g6+bios+pa&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHUP5FWJNcYKRoaAFwA3gAgAFIiAHYBJIBAjEwmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab) the answer?***  I don't see the point in relaying the results of a simple google search when the answer looks like it is right there (over and over).  If you did, please tell me what you tried.  I have ideas on what to do next if that should fail.

Comment: I tried but couldn't find any answers. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: OK.. fair enough.  Those links were duds!  This is just a guess, but pulling out your CMOS battery might do the trick.  Look in your manual for instructions to open the laptop chassis. Remove or disconnect the CMOS battery* for 6-10 minutes to erase the CMOS settings.  Put it back together.  Try again.  This may or may not work (probably will).

Comment: Pulling out CMOS battery won't work for HP probook 440 g6. Please confirm once again.

Comment: Then it looks like you are screwed.  Pay HP or have a 3rd party replace the bios chip.  Sorry. :(

Comment: If we replace the bios chip, the issue will be solved right.

Comment: enter the Wong password 3 or more times, if it outputs a code post it in the comments please.

Comment: It just shows authentication failed. No code.